# django-filter order_by "Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field"

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Using django-filter, I have the following FilterSet:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(name='full_name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name',]
        order_by_field = 'order'
        order_by = ('name',)
```

As you can see, I have named the field to `full_name` so it filters on the `full_name` column of table. But once I set the `order_by` to `name` it gives me this error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: ...

It filters with `?name=Jon%20Doe` but the ordering doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation on [Meta.order_by](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#ordering-using-order-by), you have to use a field name from the model, not a filter field name. In your case, I would just use `full_name`, which is on the model:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(name='full_name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name',]
        order_by_field = 'order'
        order_by = ('full_name',)
```

If you have a look at the code: https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filterset.py#L326-L339, you will see that if you have declared an order_by field, it loops through the form fields (generated from the model), then uses that value as an argument to order_by on the QuerySet.

If anything, the documentation should be more explicit on this fact.

Comment: I don't see anything explicitly saying it must be **model** field. `order_by can be either a list or tuple of field names`. See [name](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#name)

Comment: @norbertpy - my answer is correct. I updated it with an explanation. Feel free to verify the results through debugging by throwing print statements as I did to test.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It is right. But one question, how do you map a querystring parameter to a column name for ordering? I mean, I want my querystring have `?order=name` but instead make the ordering on `full_name` column on model. How can I do this?

Comment: The `name` of  the filter (to the left of the `=`) is what you pass to the querystring. The name within CharFilter(name=`model_field_name`). Thus, what you have is correct for what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thus, you could have a model field named `i_like_cookies`, but want to simplify it by having the querystring be `?likes_cookies=Yes|No` by doing `likes_cookies = django_filters.CharField(name='i_like_cookies')`.

Comment: This works for filtering as I said. But not for ordering and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because ordering is strictly based off of model fields. That would be a feature request for the django-filter folks. However, since all you are doing is pointing your custom filters to a model field, there would be no point in implementing the ordering by the custom field name. If I were the author, I wouldn't do it, but if I did - I would just look at the `name` keyword argument, then grab the model field name you are pointing to and use that on the back end.